# update document properties in library using csom

Tags: document-library, client-object-model

in the code below I am uploading a document to a library. This part is fine but the problem is with setting the properties of that document. I have not been able to find an example that does that. 
I have properties like "Email", "Customer" etc.

Can anyone tell me how can I set these properties when the document is uploaded?

```
   public static void UploadDocumentContentStream(string siteUrl, string libraryName, string filePath)
    {           
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);           
        ctx.RequestTimeout = 1000000;
        ctx.Credentials = Utils.GetO365Credentials("login", "123456");           
        Web web = ctx.Web;            
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))           
        {               
            FileCreationInformation flciNewFile = new FileCreationInformation();                
            // This is the key difference for the first case - using ContentStream property               
            flciNewFile.ContentStream = fs;               
            flciNewFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath);               
            flciNewFile.Overwrite = true;

            List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName); 

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);                
            ctx.Load(uploadFile);               
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code once the file is uploaded.

```
uploadFile.CheckOut();

ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["FieldName"] = "SomeFieldValue";
item.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
uploadFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model

Comment: It looks like this code only works by updating fields that are part of the file metadata (i.e. file columns), is there a way to update the folder columns (the values of the columns for that file in the folder)?

Answer (score 3):

You could also utilize [File.SaveBinaryDirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect(v=office.14).aspx) to upload the specified file to a SharePoint site.

**Example**

```
var sourceFilePath = @"C:\Users\gremyachev\Documents\SharePoint User Guide.docx";
var targetUrl = "/Shared Documents";

using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
   ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

   //Upload file
   var targetFileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", targetUrl, Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath));
   using (var fs = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open))
   {
          Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx,targetFileUrl , fs, true);
   }

    //Set document properties
    var uploadedFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(targetFileUrl);
    var listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
    listItem["DocumentType"] = "Information";
    listItem.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(flciNewFile);` add following code:

```
ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["FieldName"] = "Value";
item.Update();
ctx.Load(uploadFile);               
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload Document along with meta data using JSOM

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/ProposalRepository/SiteAssets/ProposalRepository/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var fileInput;
    var fileName;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            fileInput = $("#getFile");
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);
    });

    function registerClick() {
        //Register File Upload Click Event   
        $("#addFileButton").click(readFile);
    }
    var arrayBuffer;

    function readFile() {
        var fileVal = $("#getFile").val();

        //Get File Input Control and read th file name  
        var element = document.getElementById("getFile");
        var file = element.files[0];
        var parts = element.value.split("\\");
        fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        //Read File contents using file reader  
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName);
        }
        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            alert(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    var attachmentFiles;

    function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName) {
        //Get Client Context,Web and List object.  
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Name of your Document Library');

        //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        var i, length, out = '';
        for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1) {
            out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        var base64 = btoa(out);
        //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
        var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
        createInfo.set_content(base64);
        createInfo.set_overwrite(true); //want to overwrite the file with same name
        createInfo.set_url(fileName);

        //Add the file to the library  
        var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)
        //Load client context and execcute the batch  
        clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
    }

    function QuerySuccess() {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ProposalDocuments');
        var element = document.getElementById("getFile");
        var file = element.files[0];
        var parts = element.value.split("\\");
        fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
        var fileName = fileName;
        var collListItem;
        var oListItem;

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(
            "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value></Eq>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "</Query></View>");
        collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                console.log(oListItem.get_id());
                var docID = oListItem.get_id();  //getting file id from library
            }

            UpdateListItem('Name of your document library', docID, 'testMetaData');
        }, function(sender, args) {
            console.log("something went wrong");
            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        });

        console.log('File Uploaded Successfully.');
      //  alert("File Uploaded Successfully.");
    }

    function QueryFailure(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }


    function UpdateListItem(listName, itemId, titleVal) {

        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);

        var item = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": itemType
            },
            "Title": titleVal

        };

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success');
                alert('File Uploaded');
                window.location = "http://korbsbvm113:2728/sites/ProposalRepository/SitePages/Home.aspx";
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "Item";
    }
</script>
```

Proposal Document

```
<div class="Pagebtn">
    <input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
    <input id="cancelBtn" type="button" value="Close"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the code with:
<input id="getFile" class="ms-formlabel" type="file" />

For using this approach i have created a page and added a content editor web part. the whole code i have written in single file with extension .txt 
give the path of the file in your content editor.