# update only current added item in list

Tags: list, csom

I am updating RefCreated column in sharepoint list when new item is getting created.
Problem is if 7 items are already there and 8th item is added by user all RefCreated field of items will get updated by that user.
I want to update only current newly added item.
I am using below code.

```
uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
ListItemCollection items = docs.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items);
User currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
ctx.Load(currentUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Logger.Info("valueD" + currentUser);
foreach (var item in items)
{                                     
     item["RefCreated"] = toaddress;
     //item["ReferenceCreated"] = toaddress;

     item.Update();
     Logger.Info("valueD");
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: From the code you posted it seems that you are updating for all items using for each loop. You will need to write code in such a way that it will get only created item and do the updation for that item only

Comment: yes, can you help me with that

Comment: Hi Brishal, you will need to add more detail to your question and if possible your full code.

Comment: I have updated the code, we are uploading a new file every time code run and updating RefCreated field. but Refcreated field is getting updated for other previously added items as well.

Comment: Hi Brishal, google search "upload file with metadata using CSOM". You will get so many examples.

Comment: For eg: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121663/update-document-properties-in-library-using-csom

Comment: tried with below but no success.
ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["FieldName"] = "Value";
item.Update();
ctx.Load(uploadFile);               
ctx.ExecuteQuery();