# How to update File metadata in Sharepoint CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I know this question has been asked in the past, but I can't seem to find a working solution. I want to update The CreatedDateTime, ModifiedBy and CreatedBy metadata on a file that I uploaded with CSOM. I have this code. It does not crash, but does not update the properties either.

```
        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
        byte[] FileContent = null;
       
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
            FileContent = webClient.DownloadData(file.DowlnloadUrl);
        }

        newFile.ContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileContent);
        newFile.Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Name);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sharepointFile = _spFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
        _context.ExecuteQuery();

        sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields["Modified"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
        sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields["Created"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
        sharepointFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
        _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The file still appears that it was created/modified a few seconds ago.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. PS: if this can be done in one go (one single ExecuteQuery), that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried to update other fields like title? Will it work?

Comment: @MichaelHan_MSFT Yes, it seems to work with Title, but it creates a new version where the Title appears. I tried adding disabling the versioning and updating the Dates, but still no luck.

Comment: Ok you could  try to set the Modified field property ReadOnlyField to false, then updating the dates.

Comment: That did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very tricky. My app is running on .NetCore 3.1. Below is the endpoint I am using to generate a Token and then a ClientContext

```
            var body = $"resource={resource}&client_id={_clientId}&grant_type=password&username={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_userName)}&password={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pwd)}";
```

The clientId is my Azure App Client Id.
This code generates a Bearer token. When you decode the token, you can see the permissions you have with it. I needed the SitesFullControl delegated permission.
[image]

Once I added that permission, my Bearer token decode had it and my Update ModifiedDate worked.
I hope this can help anyone who spent days trying to figure this out like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uploadFile.CheckOut();

ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
item["FieldName"] = "SomeFieldValue";
item.Update();

// use OverwriteCheckIn type to make sure not to create multiple versions 
uploadFile.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
```

See reference: [update document properties in library using csom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121663/update-document-properties-in-library-using-csom)

or check

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model

Comment: Hi Martin. I have seen this thread and it is still not working in my case. It is very odd. I have tried multiple solutions on stackoverflow yet nothing worked for me. (Tried disabling and enabling Versionning, and it did not work either).